# Find surrounding element of source iframe in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I have a shell page that contains a number of sandboxed iframes.

e.g.

```
<div>
  <div id="sb1"><iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" srcdoc="stuff here"/></div>
  <div id="sb2"><iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" srcdoc="other stuff here"/></div>
</div>
```

When I receive a message from one of the iframes I'd like to know the parent div (i.e. #sb1 or #sb2).

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  // Follow line results in : Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin ...
  var parentDiv = $(event.source).parent();
}

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
```

Is there a way to determine the iframe's parent without having to pass an id in the message from the iframe?

Comment: Probably not, seeing as the iframes are blocked by the same-origin policy.

Comment: You can look over the `iframe`'s in the document to find the one with the matching `window` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work based on "Alexander O'Mara" comment.

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  var parentDiv = $($('iframe').toArray().find(
      function(f) {
        return f.contentWindow === event.source;
      }
    )).parent();
}

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lately i needed to know the id of the button that toggled a modal. 'relatedTarget' worked for me, it might work in your case as well.

```js
    function receiveMessage(event)
    {
     var id = event.relatedTarget.id;
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
```

Comment: relatedTarget is not defined for me.